# ionViewDidLeave and ionViewDidEnter not firing when i change pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 application with Angular 7 development, the event ionViewDidEnter works if I first enter on the page, but if I move to another page and go back this event is not firing.

I change to ngOnDestroy from Angular and this works when the page is first loaded but when I go to the page and go back and leave this not working too.

My real problem that I have a login page and a home panel page, when I start the application my ngOnInit from my app.component.ts he verifies if the user is logged if is he redirect the user to panel home page that use this code

```
this.router.navigate(['painel/home']);
```

When this happens this event **ionViewDidEnter and ionViewWillEnter** work when this page appears, but when I click my button logout, my application clear the cache and change the navigation to this page auth.component.ts this is the code from logout

```
public logout(refresh?: boolean): void {
    this.tokenStorage.clear();
    if (refresh) {
      this.router.navigate(['auth']);
    }
  }
```

Simple, but when I make a login again this events **ionViewDidEnter and ionViewWillEnter** don't fire and I want this to fire every time the user enters in panel home page, this is my code to log in application

```
async authenticationLogin() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Autenticando',
    });
    loading.present();

    const userModel: any = {
      afiliate_code: this.authForm.value.afiliate_code,
      device_uuid: this.device.uuid,
    };
    let companyCode: string = this.authForm.value.company_code;
    companyCode = companyCode.toUpperCase();

    this.auth.login(userModel, companyCode, this.uuidValidation).pipe(
    catchError(
      (error: any): Observable<any> => {
        loading.dismiss();
        return this.utilService.errorHandler(error);
      }))
    .subscribe( async response => {
      if (response.responseData.success === 1) {
        if (this.authForm.value.checkauth_param) {
          this.authParam = {
            afiliate_code: userModel.afiliate_code,
            companyCodeData: companyCode,
          };
          this.storageService.saveKeyStorage('param', this.authParam);
        } else {
          if (this.storageService.getKeyParamData('param')) {
            this.storageService.removeKeyStorage('param');
          }
        }
        this.submitted = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.authForm.reset();
        }, 2000);
        this.router.navigate(['painel/home']);
      } else if (response.responseData.success === 2) {
        this.utilService.errorMsgAlert(response.responseData.message);
      } else if (response.responseData.success === 3) {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Atenção!',
          message: 'Você ainda não possui um dispositivo vinculado, deseja vincular este dispositivo ao seu usuário?',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Não',
              role: 'cancel',
              cssClass: 'secondary'
            }, {
              text: 'Sim',
              handler: () => {
                this.uuidValidation = true;
                this.authenticationLogin();
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        await alert.present();
      } else {
        this.utilService.errorMsgAlert('Não foi possível fazer autenticação');
      }
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

That is working fine, what I'm doing wrong to not fire these events?

Comment: Try using onViewWillEnter, it's basically the same with ionViewDidEnter except ionViewWillEnter fires when entering a page, before it becomes the active one.

Comment: in your use case how do you define go back? via browser "back" or via in-app back button/arrow?

Comment: I use this command to navigate in pages Sergey this.router.navigate(['painel/home']);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem with this, I was using this code from Angular 7 core to change my pages

```
 // import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 this.router.navigate(['painel/home']);
```

But when I change to the Ionic 4 core

```
 // import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
 this.navController.navigateBack(['painel/home']);
```

Now **ionViewDidEnter** is fired every time, I read this article and solvend my problem.

Thank you all

https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subscriber to **detect a route change**

this code runs whenever your page is displayed

```
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    
    constructor(
        private routerActive:ActivatedRoute
      ) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.routerActive.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
            if (this.router.url === "/yourURL") {

              // ***** This runs whenever your page is displayed ******

            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ionViewWillEnter**, it's basically the same with ionViewDidEnter except **ionViewWillEnter** fires when entering a page, before it becomes the active one.

Comment: I will try this and see what happens